# Is it possible to append a pandas series to a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, hash, series

I have been working on project lately which predicts the most optimum team in fantasy premier league. After analysing different characteristics and parameters successfully I have been stuck because of the following "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

I have completed writing the first part of the code but received an error. I searched through the net but couldn't find a solution. One of the solution said that you cannot append series to list. Is that true? and what are the possible solutions for the same. I've come too far now, I really want to get this done properly.

```py
def my_team (budget = 100, star_player_limit = 3, gk = 2, df = 5, mid = 5, fwd = 3 ): # Pass constraints to function
    team = [ ]                          # List of team to be returned
    star_position = [ ]                 # list containing position of starplayer
    star_player_limit = star_player_limit
    budget = budget
    injured = dataset2.loc[(dataset2.loc[:,"Status"] == 'injured'),:] # Keeping a check of injury status
    positions = {"GKP":gk,"DEF":df,"MID":mid,"FWD":fwd}       # Dict accounting for no. of postions left to fill
    for ind in Top_points.index:       # Looping through the dataframe of players
        player = Top_points.loc[ind]   # Row of Dataframe one at a time
        star_position.append(player.Position)    # Checking position of star player
        if len(team) < star_player_limit and player not in injured and budget > player.Cost and positions[player.Position] > 0 and player.Position not in star_position:
            team.append(player)
            budget -= player.Cost
            positions[player.Position] -= 1

    return team
```

my_team()

After running the code I got this error: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-a7d781e901c6> in <module>()
----> 1 my_team()

<ipython-input-149-ec17dbd9b9ba> in my_team(budget, star_player_limit, gk, df, mid, fwd)
      9         player = Top_points.loc[ind]
     10         star_position.append(player.Position)
---> 11         if len(team) < star_player_limit and player not in injured and budget > player.Cost and positions[player.Position] > 0 and player.Position not in star_position:
     12             team.append(player)
     13             budget -= player.Cost

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __contains__(self, key)
   1517     def __contains__(self, key):
   1518         """True if the key is in the info axis"""
-> 1519         return key in self._info_axis
   1520 
   1521     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __contains__(self, key)
   2018     @Appender(_index_shared_docs['__contains__'] % _index_doc_kwargs)
   2019     def __contains__(self, key):
-> 2020         hash(key)
   2021         try:
   2022             return key in self._engine

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __hash__(self)
   1487     def __hash__(self):
   1488         raise TypeError('{0!r} objects are mutable, thus they cannot be'
-> 1489                         ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1490 
   1491     def __iter__(self):

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas frames are mutable. Because of that, they cannot be used as keys of a dict, or elements of a set.

Look at line 11 in the first stacktrace. I've re-formatted it to be readable.

```py
if (len(team) < star_player_limit and
    player not in injured and
    budget > player.Cost and
    positions[player.Position] > 0 and
    player.Position not in star_position):
```

We have a `player not in injured` clause here. The former is defined as

```py
player = Top_points.loc[ind]
```

I suppose its type is `Series`.

Now we have the second stacktrace, of a `__contains__` method which handles the `in` operator. In it, I suppose `self` is `injured`, and `key` is `player`.
Indeed, it can't `hash(player)`.

(It can't be the second `in` clause because `start_position` is a plain Python list, and the `__contains__` stacktrace is from pandas.)

I'd extract the name or other ID from `player`, and searched for it in `injured`; maybe I'd turn `injured` into a set of names along the way.

Comment: Thank you for your response,  But I did look into the type of 'ind' and it turned out to be an 'int' as expected      <br/> Code for testing <br/> for ind in Top_points.index:
    print(type(ind))
    row = Top_points.loc[ind]
    print(row.Position)
    print(type(row))
    print('\n')        <br/> Output: <br/>   <class 'int'>
MID
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Hey, I was wrong because I read the stacktrace wrong! I'm rewriting my answer.